# Does MediaPlayer have problems with playing files with # in their paths?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I've noticed recently that the audioplayer developed by me stopped playing.

It turned out that `MediaPlayer.prepare()` threw an exception:

```
"Prepare failed.: status=0x1"
```

The file name contained # symbol. After I removed #, it could be played back. I just removed # symbol. The file path itself was long and contained spaces, [ etc.

```
final Uri uri = Uri.parse("/storage/sdcard1/audio/Die Toten Hosen/03 - Boxed Set/2007 - Die DTH Jubiläumsedition [17 CD Boxed Set Remasted]/CD 1 - Opel-Gang/18. Radio Argentina #1.mp3");
mediaPlayer.reset();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, uri);
```

The question is why when I transfer files to my phone with

```
adb push /tmp/ /storage/sdcard1/audio/
```

and some of them contain ? symbols, then they are skipped (or an errors/warning occur. Don't remember exactly), but the files that had # in their names were copied successfully. If there are some escaping rules then problems should be the same with files containing ? and files containing #.

Because I don't see any logic in what happened. It looks like there is no central place defining what should be escaped and how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use:

```
MediaPlayer.setDataSource(String);
```

Obviously it can handle # symbol in path names.

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource("/storage/sdcard1/audio/Die Toten Hosen/03 - Boxed Set/2007 - Die DTH Jubiläumsedition [17 CD Boxed Set Remasted]/CD 1 - Opel-Gang/18. Radio Argentina #1.mp3");
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are passing a `Uri` into the `audioplayer`, `#` and `?` are special characters. Within a Uri, a hash `#` is known as a [Fragment Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier), which for example automatically skips a web page down to a certain anchor tag, or skips plaback to a given start time. A question mark `?` in a Uri allows for query paramaters, extra arguments that may be used by whatever is consuming the Uri.

As these are special characters in the context of a Uri, this is why playback is initially failing, and works once the files are renamed. You can escape these special characters by using [`URLEncoder.encode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

> **public static String encode(String s,
>               String enc)**
>                        *throws UnsupportedEncodingException*
>
> Translates a string into application/x-www-form-urlencoded format using a specific encoding scheme. This method uses the supplied encoding scheme to obtain the bytes for unsafe characters.
>   Note: The World Wide Web Consortium Recommendation states that UTF-8 should be used. Not doing so may introduce incompatibilites.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> - **s** - String to be translated.
> - **enc** - The name of a supported character encoding.
>
> **Returns:**
>   the translated String.

So in your case:

```
final String encoded = URLEncoder.encode("/storage/sdcard1/audio/Die Toten Hosen/03 - Boxed Set/2007 - Die DTH Jubiläumsedition [17 CD Boxed Set Remasted]/CD 1 Opel-Gang/18. Radio Argentina #1.mp3", "UTF-8");
final Uri uri = Uri.parse(encoded);
mediaPlayer.reset();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, uri);
```